# Flash: Optimising File Size?

Tags: flash, filesize

Just wanted to inquire about the optimisation of file size of the FLA file.. Currently, I have a 600kb .FLA file, and the music file for my program at this stage is 3.2mb. However, when I import the music into the library, I end up with a file size of 22mb.

I figure this can't be right. I understand you can just load the sound file externally but I want to have all the data in the one FLA for the sake of ease, as I will be porting my program to iPhone, and low file size is therefore ideal.

Hence, I just wanted to ask about optimising file size? I read about "Save to Compact", however, I am using Flash CS5, and so such an option is not available.

I guess I'm just at loss to understand how a 3MB .mp3 can contribute 21.x megabytes to my FLA file?

Has anybody got tips on reducing this crazy file size?

Thanks!
Harry.

Comment: It sounds like your MP3 is being decoded/converted to a WAV file when you import it?

Comment: how can i combat this / stop it from happening? i tried going into the file's properties in the library and changing the compression to MP3 but the filesize didn't change.

Comment: How are you using the mp3?  on the timeline? Are you able to post you .fla?

Comment: If in the mp3 properties in flash you have it set MP3 with the same compression, then it should not increase your file-size more than roughly it's original size (eg. around 3.5 mb)

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices - you would think so, but no matter what settings I set for the mp3 file, it tells me: "22kHz Stereo 16 Bit 208.1s 18352.6 kB - so the filesize is wrecked for some reason?

Comment: That is odd, are you able to post the fla so I/someone can look at it directly?

Comment: well, i compressed the MP3 to 200kb and now the .FLA is 3mb, which is still not right.. it seems to be scaling up the mp3 within the FLA. anyway, i'm not comfortable with uploading my FLA (lots and lots of work), but here's an empty FLA with the exact same 200kb mp3, and, sure enough, the filesize is disproportionate. do i need to get my sound guy to re-export the mp3 file? something isn't right with it.. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17926052/theFLA.fla (note: CS5.0 fla)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Instead of having multiple scenes, have one scene.
2. Practice add/remove movieclip when needed/not needed instead of having movieclips in the stage always
3. Do not have a large number of movieclips in the stage because each movieclip barely occupies **4 bytes** of memory
4. **If you are having more small movieclips for decorating your buttons of having filters for your movieclips then replace those with the image.(FYI, You can export image from flash)**
5. If possible try to use **FLASH CS6**, because it avail sprite sheet concept for animations, it can reduce considerable amount of size of your file and ease of animations.
6. If possible try to load the sound file from the server to reduce the size. It can take few seconds/minutes and it could be tolerable
7. Clean the library to delete unused or unwanted graphics or movieclips by 
   Library -> Click on the right most -> Select Unused Items from that popup
8. Unused items selected and delete those from the library.

Hope this will reduce a considerable amount of size.

Comment: some good insight and helpful suggestions here. i'll be referencing this in the future as my projects get larger in file size. thanks :)